# Função maior numero em uma árvore

Tags: c

Estou desenvolvendo uma função de me retornar o maior número de uma árvore.
Estou tentando esse código, mas não obtive sucesso em sua compilação, imprimindo `-1` na tela, enquanto era para imprimir apenas o maior número da árvore.

```
int maiorNum(tipo_arvore * raiz)
{
 if(raiz != NULL)
  return maiorNum(raiz->dir);
 else
  return -1;
 }
```

Comment: E onde você verifica se um valor é maior que outro?

Comment: Ele só vai me retornar o valor não é? Que é o da direita.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, mas da erro na compilação na linha `if((raiz->dir) && (raiz->dir->inf > raiz->inf))`

Comment: Colocar qual é a definição de `tipo_arvore` também é essencial.

Comment: Sim eu coloquei. Mas mesmo assim da erro na linha. Não sei o que é.

Comment: Essencial na pergunta, para entendermos o que você está fazendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O primeiro passo que eu faço durante a resolução de um problema é saber com o que estou lidando. No nosso caso, temos uma árvore binária em que todos os nós, não apenas as folhas, tem valor real (ie, não apenas valores indexantes). Não foi fornecido pelo André se a árvore é de busca ou não, apesar de que em seu trecho de código ele deixar isso implícito. Vou responder aqui para ambos os casos.

## Árvore binária generalizada

Uma árvore é um estrutura que é dada pelas seguintes regras:

1. um nó é um elemento constituinte de uma árvore,
2. um nó tem no máximo um único nó pai,
3. um nó pode não ter pai, esse caso ele é chamado de raiz.

Além disso, temos alguns conceitos/conclusões derivados dessas definições:

1. se `A`, `B` e `C` tem como nó pai `X`, diz-se que `A`, `B` e `C` são nós filhos de `X`,
2. uma folha é um nó que não possui filhos,
3. a árvore mais simples é composta apenas da raiz,
4. um nó, seus filhos e todos os seus descendentes constituem uma subárvore,
5. dois nós pertencem a mesma árvore se eles compartilham a mesma raiz,
6. se eu só navegar de um nó qualquer para seu nó filho, nunca acontecerá de eu encontrar o mesmo nó descendente por dois caminhos distintos.

Uma árvore binária é uma especificação da árvore generalizada; ela possui as mesmas regras de formação e também a seguinte:

1. para uma árvore ser binária, todo nó está limitada a ter, no máximo, 2 nós filhos.

Como conceito adicional, temos que os nós filhos são identificados por **nó a esquerda** e **nó a direita**.

Para percorrer uma árvore binária, preciso passar pela raiz, pela subárvore à esquerda (aquela formada pelo nó a esquerda) e pela subárvore à direita. A ordem pela qual eu passo por cada um desses 3 elementos a grosso modo é indiferente.

Então, se eu fizer a visita na ordem **nó, esquerda, direita**, tenho mais ou menos esse algoritmo:

```
navega_arvore(nodo subarvore):
    visita(subarvore)
    se subarvore->esquerda != null:
        navega_arvore(subarvore->esquerda)
    se subarvore->direita != null:
        navega_arvore(subarvore->direita)
```

Essa é a estrutura geral da navegação. No caso de o nó ter um valor indicado por `inf`, e querermos pegar o maior `inf` possível, temos esse algoritmo:

```
maior_inf_arvore(nodo subarvore):
    inf_atual = subarvore->inf

    maior_inf = inf_autal # até encontrar um filho com uma informação maior, o maior que eu tenho é o atual
    se subarvore->esquerda != null:
        inf_esquerda = maior_inf_arvore(subarvore->esquerda)

        se inf_esquerda > maior_inf:
            maior_inf = inf_esquerda
    se subarvore->direita != null:
        inf_direita = maior_inf_arvore(subarvore->direita)

        se inf_direita > maior_inf:
            maior_inf = inf_direita
    retorne maior_inf
```

Na recursão, eu garanto que vou passar por todos os nós descendentes do nó passado. Também garanto que, após essa navegação, vou obter a maior informação possível dentro da subárvore.

Em C, aquele algoritmo fica mais ou menos assim:

```
int maior_inf_arvore(tipo_arvore *subarvore) {
    int maior_inf, inf_atual, inf_esquerda, inf_direita;

    inf_atual = subarvore->inf;

    maior_inf = inf_autal; /* até encontrar um filho com uma informação maior, o maior que eu tenho é o atual */
    if (subarvore->esquerda != null) {
        inf_esquerda = maior_inf_arvore(subarvore->esq);

        if (inf_esquerda > maior_inf) {
            maior_inf = inf_esquerda;
        }
    }
    if (subarvore->direita != null) {
        inf_direita = maior_inf_arvore(subarvore->dir);

        if (inf_direita > maior_inf) {
            maior_inf = inf_direita;
        }
    }
    return maior_inf;
}
```

## Árvore binária de busca

Uma árvore binária de busca é uma árvore binária que tem as seguintes regras a mais:

1. todo nó tem uma informação comparável,
2. o nó filho a esquerda tem informação menor do que a do seu pai,
3. o nó filho a direita tem informação maior do que ou igual a do seu pai.

Então, em cima dessa definição, não precisamos navegar à esquerda. Também temos a garantia de que, se tem um filho à direita, esse filho tem uma informação maior, portanto não devo considerar a informação do original. Assim, em pseudo-código, ficaria:

```
maior_inf_arvore_busca(nodo subarvore):
    se subarvore->direita != null:
        retorne maior_inf_arvore(subarvore->direita)
    senão:
        retorne subarvore->inf
```

Em C:

```
int maior_inf_arvore_busca(tipo_arvore *subarvore) {
    if (subarvore->dir != null) {
        return maior_inf_arvore(subarvore->dir);
    } else {
        return subarvore->inf;
    }
}
```

Só que essa é uma estratégia recursiva simples. Poderia ser trocada por uma simples iteração:

```
int maior_inf_arvore_busca(tipo_arvore *subarvore):
    tipo_arvore *navegacao = subarvore
    while (navegacao->dir != null) {
        navegacao = navegacao->dir;
    }

    return navegacao-> inf;
}
```

## NOTA

Eu não fiz o tratamento de se passar a raiz da árvore nula, mas é fácil fazer isso.

Comment: Excelente explicação que deixou tudo mais claro, realmente quando sabemos que queremos o maior número de uma árvore binária de busca não necessitamos olhar a esquerda, o código recursivo ajuda a ficar mais enxuto.

Comment: Eu tentei adicionar: `if(raiz->dir ==NULL) {
        return 0;
    }` mas não deu certo.

Comment: Mais tarde eu faço o tratamento e coloco na resposta

Answer (score -1):

Amigo tenta colocar `tipo_arvore` em vez do `int`.

Vou editar aqui porque alguém deixou como negativo minha resposta.

```
tipo_arvore * maior(tipo_arvore * raiz)
{
  if((raiz->dir) && (raiz->dir > raiz->inf))
    return maior(raiz->dir);
  else
    return raiz->inf;
}
```

Comment: Amigo tenta retirar o `-> inf`, ficando assim `if((raiz->dir) && (raiz->dir > raiz->inf))`

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado, mas teria que fazer uma verificação antes. Vou tentar aqui.

Comment: @TiagoPereira , `inf` é inteiro e `dir` é ponteiro para `tipo_arvore`. Como estamos sob a tag `c`, não temos sobre carga de operadores, então o `<` vai comparar o endereço indicado pelo ponteiro e o inteiro

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado você viu que mudei a pergunta aí? Por favor me ajude a achar o erro. Grato

Comment: Essa resposta está completamente errada, porque você retorna um tipo int e declara o retorno como tipo_arvore* ??? Acredito que a árvore já esteja ordenada (senão o código não faz sentido algum), porém mesmo ordenada não faz sentido o (raiz->dir > raiz->inf).